# Google Sheets - Retrieve contents of the last modified cell in a workbook

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm building a dynamic validation list, the missing ingredient is the following

I need to populate a cell (A1) with the contents of the last modified cell in a workbook.

I dont know the column/row/sheet of the cell i want to retrieve its content. So basically it is the last entry, and it can be anywhere in the workbook

Any chance of doing that?

Comment: If you want to keep track of last modified entry & cell , you can OnEdit Event and create another sheet in the which record and cell reference and newValue. On whenever the sheet is edited, you can update that range with cell reference which is edited along with its value

Comment: I appreciate your prompt response. But i want the value to be written in a certain cell in the same sheet. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that data will be stored in sheet named lastModifiedRange

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('lastModifiedRange')
  sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(e.value);
  sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName());
  sheet.getRange('A3').setValue(e.source.getActiveRange().getA1Notation());
  sheet.getRange('A4').setValue(e.oldValue);
}
```

edit : if you want to write it in the same sheet

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet=e.source.getActiveSheet()
  sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(e.value);
}
```

Comment: That is super! thank you very much

Comment: You can accept this answer, to close this thread.

Comment: Yeah i got the concept, moving it to the cell and sheet i want to write the values in! Awesome stuff thanks again